# How would I go about leveling a sagging floor?

Tags: floor, level

I had all my kitchen cabinets refaced last year.  I than decided to replace the counters with granite.  When the guy from the counter company came out he did some leveling test. I am putting counters on three sections of counters.  It seem that one side of my kitchen is higher than the rest.  He suspects the floor is unlevel and it is out of the 3/4 variance he can correct by shims. Two sides of the cabinets are on outside walls.

My basement is finished was remodeled a couple years back. I am really wanting to know what my options are how I would level the floor without tearing up what I already finished. What is the average and what type of skill set should I reaching out to get this solved?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to fix this.

- have the cabinets installed correctly.  They should have been shimmed to at least very close to level.  This is basically a one day job and isn't rocket science.  You unscrew cabinets and shim them.  Front bases have to be redone.  If someone installed these for you I would call that company to come back out.
- install plywood over cabinets.  Have it planed/sanded to meet the needs (this will be difficult).

Comment: The cabinets **are** installed, aren't they?  But now so far out of level that you can't shim between the cabinet top and the new granite counter?

Comment: The cabinets are existing and have been refaced.  They are quite beautiful now.  And yes so far out of level that shim is not a option for the granite guy.

Comment: @User58220 - will edit my answer.